# Strange query plan on max(date) query on a View

Tags: sql-server, sql-execution-plan

I have a view which comprises 4 yearly tables:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[BGT_BETWAYDETAILS]
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT [bwd_BetTicketNr] ,
    [bwd_LineID] [int] ,
    [bwd_ResultID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [bwd_DateModified]  ,
    [bwd_DateModifiedTrunc]  ,
    [bwd_LineMaxPayout] 
FROM   [dbo].[BGT_BETWAYDETAILS_2020]
UNION ALL
SELECT [bwd_BetTicketNr] ,
    [bwd_LineID] [int] ,
    [bwd_DateModified]  ,
    [bwd_DateModifiedTrunc]  ,
    [bwd_LineMaxPayout] 
FROM   [dbo].[BGT_BETWAYDETAILS_2019]
UNION ALL
SELECT [bwd_BetTicketNr] ,
    [bwd_LineID] [int] ,
    [bwd_DateModified]  ,
    [bwd_DateModifiedTrunc]  ,
    [bwd_LineMaxPayout] 
FROM   [dbo].[BGT_BETWAYDETAILS_2018]
UNION ALL
SELECT [bwd_BetTicketNr] ,
    [bwd_LineID] [int] ,
    [bwd_DateModified]  ,
    [bwd_DateModifiedTrunc]  ,
    [bwd_LineMaxPayout] 
FROM   [dbo].[BGT_BETWAYDETAILS_2017];
GO
```

Each table has the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BGT_BETWAYDETAILS_2020]
(
    [bwd_BetTicketNr] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [bwd_LineID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [bwd_ResultID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [bwd_DateModified] [datetime] NULL,
    [bwd_DateModifiedTrunc] [date] NULL,
    [bwd_LineMaxPayout] [decimal](18, 4) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [CSTR__BGT_BETWAYDETAILS_2020_CKEY] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([bwd_BetTicketNr] ASC, [bwd_LineID] ASC, [bwd_ResultID] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I have added an non-clustered index on

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCI__DATEMODIFIED] 
ON [dbo].[BGT_BETWAYDETAILS_2020] ([bwd_DateModifiedTrunc] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, 
                          ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I am running the following 3 queries:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX([bwd_DateModifiedTrunc]), '2019-01-01') AS next_date
FROM [dbo].[BGT_BETWAYDETAILS_2020]

SELECT COALESCE(MAX([bwd_DateModifiedTrunc]), '2019-01-01') AS next_date
FROM [dbo].[BGT_BETWAYDETAILS]

SELECT COALESCE(CAST(MAX([bwd_DateModified]) AS date), '2019-01-01') AS next_date
FROM [dbo].[BGT_BETWAYDETAILS]
```

The first one, when run on each yearly table, runs instantly.

The second one, seems to take forever. The query plan for this, seems very strange.

[image]

The plan shows two index scans on each yearly table.

The plan for each yearly table is what I expected to see:

[image]

Finally, the plan on the non-indexed date column is also what I expected to see (a clustered index scan). A clustered index scan on each table. This query runs in ~3mins which is expected.

[image]

What is the issue here? Some anti-pattern I am missing? Why the index scan on the non-clustered index is done 2 times according to the live plan? I expected the view to respond as fast as the individual tables.

For the record, I am running this on SQL Server 2017.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214461/discussion-on-question-by-rpd-strange-query-plan-on-maxdate-query-on-a-view).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This just looks like an optimiser limitation. I have submitted [a suggestion that this should be improved](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/40496701-scalargbaggtotop-transformation-with-max-nullable).

A simpler example is

```
CREATE TABLE T1(X INT NULL UNIQUE CLUSTERED);
CREATE TABLE T2(X INT NULL UNIQUE CLUSTERED);

INSERT INTO T1 
OUTPUT INSERTED.X INTO T2
SELECT TOP 100000 NULLIF(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1/0),1) 
FROM sys.all_objects o1, 
     sys.all_objects o2;
```

And then

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT X FROM T1
UNION ALL
SELECT X FROM T2
)
SELECT MAX(X)
FROM CTE
OPTION (QUERYRULEOFF ScalarGbAggToTop)
```

This disables the query optimizer rule `ScalarGbAggToTop` and the query plan does a `MAX` on each individual table then computes a `MAX` of the `MAX`-es - so the same as

```
SELECT MAX(MaxX)
FROM 
(
SELECT MAX(X) AS MaxX FROM T1 
UNION ALL
SELECT MAX(X) AS MaxX FROM T1 
) T
```

[image]

With the `ScalarGbAggToTop` rule enabled the plan now looks like this

[image]

It is effectively doing the following...

```
SELECT MAX(MaxX)
FROM   (SELECT MAX(X) AS MaxX
        FROM   (SELECT TOP 1 X
                FROM   T1
                WHERE  X IS NULL
                UNION ALL
                SELECT TOP 1 X
                FROM   T1
                WHERE  X IS NOT NULL
                ORDER  BY X DESC) T1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT MAX(X) AS MaxX
        FROM   (SELECT TOP 1 X
                FROM   T2
                WHERE  X IS NULL
                UNION ALL
                SELECT TOP 1 X
                FROM   T2
                WHERE  X IS NOT NULL
                ORDER  BY X DESC) T2) T0
```

... but in a very inefficient way. Running the SQL above would give a plan with seeks and each branch only reading a single row.

The plan produced by `ScalarGbAggToTop` only has minimal changes to the stream aggregate plan. It looks like it takes the scan from that and applies a backwards ordering to it and then uses the backwards ordering for both the `NOT NULL` and `NULL` branches. And does not perform any additional exploration to see if there is a more efficient access path.

This means that in the pathological case that all of the rows are either `NULL` or `NOT NULL` one of the scans will end up reading all of the rows in the table (5 billion in your case if applicable to all 4 tables). Even if there is a mix of `NULL` and `NOT NULL` the fact that the `IS NULL` branch is doing a backwards scan is sub optimal because `NULL` is ordered first in SQL Server so would be at the beginning of the index.

The addition of a `NOT NULL` branch in the first place seems largely unnecessary as the query would return the same results without it. I imagine it is only needed so that it knows whether or not to display the message

> Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET
>   operation.

but I doubt you care about that. In which case adding an explicit `WHERE ... NOT NULL` resolves the issue.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT X FROM T1
UNION ALL
SELECT X FROM T2
)
SELECT MAX(X)
FROM CTE
WHERE X IS NOT NULL
;
```

It now has a seek into the `NOT NULL` part of the index and reads backwards (stopping after the first row is read from each table)

[image]

Comment: This answer is accepted because indeed solves the issue and runs on the expected time.